# wp_admin page redirect to localhost in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xampp

i want to set paramlink in wordpress. but my wp_admin redirect me to localhost.where should i get paramlink setting in WP folder?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Place this in your wp-config.php and reload the page a few times. (Replace http://example.com/ with the actual url of your site.)

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

If that doesn't work, try putting it into the functions.php file in your theme.

[Source and more information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: this was an awesome save for me thanks!! I had set the values in the database to the correct new URL but for some reason it was still not working :/